# apt update skip a url

Tags: apt, upgrade

I need to skip a broken url during apt update, gives error 403.

I know that the url will probably be fixed by next week but I need to apt upgrade my other packages now.

how do I skip one url during apt update so I can successfully update my list of packages in order to run apt upgrade?

Comment: The simplest way would be to edit the file that contains that URL, adding a `#` to the start of the line to comment it out. The file would most likely be found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` if you're running Ubuntu. Alternatively, if you're using Ubuntu Desktop, you can control this via the Software Update UI by unchecking the repository that is issuing the 403.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply *disable* (not delete) the source from your list.

- Shell: Comment out the line. Start the line with a `#`. When you want to reactivate it, remove the `#`.
- Graphically: Open Software & Updates. Locate the source. Uncheck it. When you want to reactivate it, restore the checkmark.